# NetwokX, Barabasi-Albert model

Tags: python, networkx

I have a problem with the plot of a NetworkX Barabasi-Albert graph; I would like the nodes to be colored in by a radial gradient. For now they are lime.

```python
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, 
                       pos=p,
                       node_size=5, 
                       alpha=0.5,        
                       node_color='xkcd:lime')
```

How do I change them to a radial color gradient? Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by radial color gradient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cmap from the matplotlib library.

Here are the names of the color maps you can use: https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html

Then your code would look something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')

sequence_value=[0,1,2,8,4,17] #some values you want your nodes to be colored by (if you just simply want them in different colors you could also write

# sequence_value=range(0,14) # in this case you have 14 nodes (this list must always be as long as your len(G.nodes).

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, 
                   pos=p,
                   node_size=5, 
                   alpha=0.5,        
                   node_color=sequence_value, 
                   cmap=cmap)
```